# In this for/each statement, why do I need to specify an each method using &block in the class of the object I am iterating through?

Tags: ruby, class, block

That title is not the best, so I will explain further here.

I have a Card class and a Deck class, and in Main, I am creating a Deck of Cards and then printing out all the Cards in the Deck. I've made a to_string method for Card (below):

```
def to_string
 puts "#{self.rank} of #{self.suit}"
end
```

and then used that and a for/each statement in Main to print all the Cards in Deck:

```
for card in deck
  puts card.to_string
end
```

But I received an error saying that there was an "undefined method 'each' for #Deck: (NoMethodError). I did some searching and found that the solution was to add this method to my Deck class:

```
def each(&block)
 @deck.each(&block)
end
```

I do understand (or, I think I do) how `.each` works, as I used it in creating all the Card objects for my Deck--it will go through an array and grab each array item in turn. So it made sense that `for card in deck` is basically `deck.each`. But I'm not really sure what `&block` is doing here. I did some research on what blocks are (to my understanding, basically "anonymous code"--so for example, the instructions inside of a `array.each` statement. A method that isn't a formally written method) but I still don't know what `&block` itself does.

Answer (score 1):

Every method in Ruby can (but doesn't have to) take an optional block argument, denoted with an ampersand `&` before the argument name. This argument is given the value of an explicit block when the method is called.

We can see this behavior explicitly by writing a function which simply returns its block.

```
def foo(&block)
  p block
end
```

Then if we run

```
> foo() # Note: No block argument
nil
> foo { 1 } # Note: Block provided
#<Proc:0x...>
```

So if you pass an explicit block to a method, it gets passed as a `Proc` object to the method. This is how `.each` works. The line

```
[1, 2, 3].each { |x| puts x }
```

calls `each` on `[1, 2, 3]`, passing a block argument whose `call` method runs `puts x`. You can think of it as similar to

```
[1, 2, 3].each(->(x) { puts x })
```

Here, we pass a regular argument which happens to be a lambda. This is *not* equivalent to the above (block arguments are treated as special), but we could theoretically have implemented `each` either way; the block syntax is just more convenient.

As you've correctly surmised, `for` loops desugar to something kind of like `.each`. Roughly speaking, the following two are equivalent.

```
for i in [1, 2, 3]
  foo i
end
```

```
i = nil
[1, 2, 3].each do |i|
  foo i
end
```

Note that `for` loops actually go to additional effort to ensure that the variable *does* escape the loop scope, whereas using `.each` directly produces a local-only variable that doesn't escape. For this reason, `.each` is generally considered more idiomatic in Ruby anyway, and most Ruby code shies away from explicit `for` loops in general. (IMO `.each` is also prettier and more consistent with all of the other aspects of Ruby syntax)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I succeed to clarify this properly, just a try...
Actually `for item in deck` is actually syntax sugar for those, that previously learned some procedural language, like Pascal or C, and is equivalent for method call: `deck.each { |item| ... }`. The part in curly brackets is a `block` or anynomous function. So, your code:

```ruby
for card in deck
   puts card
```

Is actually translated to call of `each` on `deck` object:

```ruby
deck.each { |card| puts card }
```

What actually does this method - you define it for collection of something and it should pass its item one after another to given `block`. And inside block we can use those item as a variable with name we like (`card` in example).
You can actually ignore item in block, for example:

```ruby
deck.each { puts "Hello" }
```

And if your deck has 52 cards, you'll see 52 times "Hello".
What is most interesting, is that having defined only this `each` method you actually can have a bunch of others, like count, min, max, map, etc. For this, you only need to include mixin `Enumerable` in your class.
Like this:

```ruby
class Deck
  include Enumerable

  def each(&block)
    @deck.each(&block)
```

And now, if you call `deck.count` it will actually return 52, or whatever is the number of cards, you've put there.
How it works: it actually executes something like:

```ruby
c = 0
deck.each { c = c + 1 }
c
```

Well, hope that helps...

Answer (score 0):

> why do I need to specify an `each` method using `&block` in the class of the object I am iterating through?

You don't have to use the `&block` syntax.

`each` is supposed to yield each element to the given block, e.g.:

```
class Foo
  def each
    yield 1
    yield 2
    yield 3
  end
end
```

```
foo = Foo.new

for i in foo
  puts i
end

# or more idiomatic:

foo.each do |i|
  puts i
end
```

Since you rarely yield hard-coded values, there's usually some kind of loop within `each`, e.g.:

```
class Foo
  def each
    1.upto(3) do |i|
      yield i
    end
  end
end
```

In your case, the loop is based on `@deck.each`, so you could write:

```
def each
  @deck.each do |card|
    yield card
  end
end
```

In order to make `each` more useful, it should also return an enumerator if no block is given:

```
def each
  return enum_for(:each) unless block_given?

  @deck.each do |card|
    yield card
  end
end
```

So what about that `&block` syntax?

If you read the documentation for [`Array#each`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.1/Array.html#each-method) you might notice that it already does all these things – it yields the elements to the block and returns an enumerator if no block is given. So you *could* avoid writing the above code just by passing the block that was given to *your* `each` along to `Array#each`.

But how can we refer to the given block? That's what the `&block` syntax is for – it assigns the block to a *variable* `block` which can be passed as a [block argument](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.1/doc/syntax/methods_rdoc.html#label-Block+Argument) to another method using the same `&block` syntax:

```
def each(&block)
  @deck.each(&block)
end
```

---

Some considerations:

- you should avoid `for` and prefer `each`-style loops
- `to_string` should just *return* the string, not print it. You can omit `self` and you should call it `to_s`:

  ```
  def to_s
    "#{rank} of #{suit}"
  end
  ```

  which allows you to directly `puts` your card:

  ```
  deck.each do |card|
    puts card
  end
  ```
- it might be cleaner to call the method `each_card`